# In Mysql datatable duplicate values for foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have two data-tables. At the first table i have an id column which is int(10) not specify as unsigned.At the second table i made a foreign key reference for the first primary key also with int(10) without specify.

Without creating the whole table shema:

```
Table1:id int(10)
Table2:id int(10),id_tab1 int(10)
```

The problem is when i try to insert new values to the second table,and want to choose
one value from the foreign key field the values like:

```
-1 1-<br>
//between these values i can see a space value strange
-2 2-
```

It is strange, i already tried to use unsigned integer for table1 but it has not solve the problem. I dont know why is duplicate one values.

[image]

Comment: You have no problem there. Values are displayed like that by your choice of DB management tool. Check raw values (e.g. in command line), you will see they are correct.

Comment: this is the first time i have this experience,by other tables(in the same database) there is no this issue.But how can i dissable this and having only one normal value?